# Error in getting access token from Salesforce

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, salesforce, .net-core

We are building a .net based application that uses salesforce in the back end. We are using OAuth 2 for authentication using WebView.

We are getting an issue while authorising.

When we try to Login using OAuth 2, the web view takes credentials, shows authorization screen and then provide an authorization code.

Once getting authorization code we use this code to generate access token but when sending the code to get the access token. it gives 400 Bad requests errors.

This happens only in the production environment and running fine on  Sandbox. Even sometimes in production, it works but most of the time throws 400 bad requests.

My connected app is defined in the sandbox and is fully configured.

my request

```
https://xxx.x-force.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code
&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3X
HrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&redirect_uri=my-callback-urlp
```

after recieving  authorization code we send a post request `https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`
with following parameters

```
grant_type
client_secret
client_id
redirect_uri
code
```

Are we missing something?

Please let me know if i need to add c# code files too?

Regards,

Manish Kumar